# heat transfer for spherical coordinates using matlab

Tags: matlab, transfer, heat

I want to apply heat transfer ( heat conduction and convection) for a hemisphere. It is a transient homogeneous heat transfer in spherical coordinates. There is no heat generation. Boundary conditions of hemisphere is in the beginning at Tinitial= 20 degree room temperature. External-enviromental temperature is -30 degree. You can imagine that hemisphere is a solid material. Also, it is a non-linear model, because thermal conductivity is changing after material is frozen, and this going to change the temperature profile.

I want to find the temperature profile of this solid during a certain time until center temperature reach to -30degree.

In this case, Temperature depends on 3 parameters : T(r,theta,t). radius, angle, and time.

1/α(∂T(r,θ,t))/∂t =1/r^2*∂/∂r(r^2(∂T(r,θ,t))/∂r)+  1/(r^2*sinθ )∂/∂θ(sinθ(∂T(r,θ,t))/∂θ)

I applied finite difference method using matlab, however program does not calculate anything for inner nodes of the hemisphere, and just giving me initial temperatures values (Which is Told in here) . You can see some scripts which i used for inner nodes.

```
% initial conditions
Tair    =   -30.0;               % Temperature of air
Tin     =    21; 

% setting initial values for grid
for i=1:(nodes)
    for j=1:(nodes)
Told(i,j)     =   Tin;
Tnew(i,j)     =   Tin;
frozen(i)   =   0;                      
latent(i)   =   Qs*mass(i)*Water/dt;    
k(i)        =   0.5;                    
cp(i)       =   cw;                     
W(i)        =   Water;                  
l(i)        =   0;                      
S(i)        =   1-Water;                
     end
end


%Simulation conditions
J       =    9;              % No. of space steps   
nodes   =   J+1;             % Number of nodes along radius or theta direction
dt      =0.1;


t       =   0;               % time index on start
tmax    =   7000;            % Time simmulation is supposed to run


R       =  d/2;

dr      =  (d/2)/J;         %  space steps in r direction

 y   =        pi/2;        % (theta) for hemisphere
dy      =  (pi/2)/J;       % space steps in Theta direction

    % Top surface condition for hemisphere
      i=nodes; 
        for j=1:1:(nodes-1) 

       Qcd_ot(i,j) = ((k(i)+ k(i-1))/2)*A(i-1)*(( Told(i,j)-Told(i-1,j))/(dr)); % heat conduction out of nod 

        Qcv(i,j) = h*(Tair-Told(i,j))*A(i); % heat transfer through convectioin on surface 

        Tnew(i,j) = ((Qcv(i,j)-Qcd_ot(i,j))/(mass(i)*cp(i))/2)*dt + Told(i,j); 
          end             %end of for loop 

  % Temperature profile for inner nodes

  for i=2:1:(nodes-1)     
    for j=2:1:(nodes-1)  

Qcd_in(i,j)=   ((k(i)+ k(i+1))/2)*A(i) *((2/R)*(( Told(i+1,j)-Told(i,j))/(2*dr)) + ((Told(i+1,j)-2*Told(i,j)+Told(i-1,j))/(dr^2)) + ((cot(y)/(R^2))*((Told(i,j+1)-Told(i,j))/(2*dy))) + (1/(R^2))*(Told(i,j+1)-2*Told(i,j)+ Told(i,j-1))/(dy^2));
Qcd_out(i,j)=  ((k(i)+ k(i-1))/2)*A(i-1)*((2/R)*(( Told(i,j)-Told(i-1,j))/(2*dr)) +((Told(i+1,j)-2*Told(i,j)+Told(i-1,j))/(dr^2)) + ((cot(y)/(R^2))*((Told(i,j)-Told(i,j-1))/(2*dy))) + (1/(R^2))*(Told(i,j+1)-2*Told(i,j)+ Told(i,j-1))/(dy^2));

Tnew(i,j)     =   (Qcd_in(i,j)-Qcd_out(i,j))/(mass(i)*cp(i)))*dt + Told(i,j);
    end           
end               

   %bottom of the hemisphere solid
  Tnew(:,nodes)=-30;



 Told=Tnew;
 t=t+dt;
```

**EDIT**  *Thanks, now the scripts are working and calculating. And i can see temperature profile for model system.

However, i want to plot in a 2D or 3D plot for this hemisphere temperature profile. Also if it is possible i would like to run animation for temperature change during certain time. The codes what i am using for simulation and to write a file is

```
     t=0;

    tmax=7000;
    ...................
    .....................
    ss=0;   % index for printouts

     %start simulation
     while t<tmax
   ss=ss+1;
  .............
  .................
   ................
    if ss==2000
    dlmwrite('d:\Results_for_model.txt',Tnew,'-append');
    ss=0;
    end


    end   % end of while loop
```

Do you have any suggestion for it ?  Because in text file, for Tnew(i,j) values, after every 10 rows, model calculates for next dt value. Therefore, results data looks like a mess, after every 10 rows, it gives for next time values results.

Is there any way to coordinate to write this results according to specific rows and columns ( because otherwise huge amount of data are needed to be organized again and again) ?

and i want to plot in 3d plot for this temperature profile which is hemisphere in this case, i have Tnew(r,theta,t), but i am confused to how to represent this temperature profile to show in a hemisphere graph. I would like to hear your suggestions about it. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: your loops run from 9 to 2 so thus don't run?

Comment: `i = (nodes-1):2 = (J+1-1):2 = 9:2` which is an immediately terminating loop

Comment: syntax is `for counter = start:optional step:end`

Comment: In addition to the above, nodes doesn't appear to be defined in the initialization section of the code, **for i=1:nodes** etc.

Comment: hahaha just beat me to it, nice catch

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply.Although i have changed the loop from 9 to 1 ,it is still doesnt calculate the nodes.i=nodes is for the surface boundary condition, and after i applied i=nodes with this scripts `i=nodes;
        for j=1:(nodes-1)    
Qcd_ot(i,j)       =   ((k(i)+ k(i-1))/2)*A(i-1)*(( Told(i,j)-Told(i-1,j))/(dr));  % heat conduction out of nod
Qcv(i,j)              =   h*(Tair-Told(i,j))*A(i);                                % heat transfer through convectioin on surface
Tnew(i,j)         =   ((Qcv(i,j)-Qcd_ot(i,j))/(mass(i)*cp(i))/2)*dt + Told(i,j);
        end       % end of for loop`

Comment: please update the original post with your new code - it's quite difficult to read in a comment

Comment: Ya, sure , i am updating, by the way codes are working, thanks a lot. but i have another issues which i mentioned in original post again

Comment: hmmm you don't seem to be updating Told? maybe?

Comment: Actually, i found the reason why it is not updating, because  inner nodes my 'for loop' is starting from `for i=2:1:9  for j=2:1:9` which is not covering i=1 and j=1 elements. after i changed it to `for i=1:1:9 for j=1` now it is updating Told values according to model

Comment: However, i have another issue in this model about writing data and 3d plot , i just updated  the original post. I would like to hear your comments.  Thanks in advance !!

Comment: hmmm, I'm not sure I follow completely - If you want T(r,theta) vs time, why not store it in a 3D matrix T(r,theta,t) exactly as you had said? No need to write to file. Then you can use Matlab's plotting tools to graph it. Am i missing something? Also this would probably be better posted as a new question so more people would help you quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise, the proper syntax as defined by MATLAB for the `for loop` construct is

```
for index = values
    program statements
    ...
end
```

where `values` has one of the following forms:

`initval:endval`

`initval:step:endval`

`valArray`

your code is parsed to `initval:endval` = `9:2`, which means the loop runs 0 times, resulting in no calculations.